# If loop in for loop in method not printing in main

Tags: java, for-loop, methods

```
import java.util.*;

public class userInputDoubleArray
{
   private static double getAverage(double[] nums){
      double sum = 0;
      for (int y= 0; y < nums.length; y++)
      {
         sum= sum + nums[y];
      }    
      return sum;
   }

   private static void showLargerValues(double[] nums, double avg)
   {  
      for (int z= 0; z < nums.length; z++)
      {
         if (nums[z] > avg)
         {
            System.out.print("The numbers higher than average are     " + nums[z] + "     ");
         }
      }    

   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      double[] nums = new double[10];
      Scanner inp= new Scanner (System.in);

      for (int i= 0; i < nums.length; i++)
      { 
         System.out.println("Please enter a double.");
         nums[i]= inp.nextDouble();
      }

      double average = getAverage(nums);

      System.out.println("The average is " + average);
      showLargerValues(nums, average);

   }
}
```

Right, so I'm trying to print out the numbers > than the average. My issue is that while it compiles, it seems like the for/if showLargerValues method isn't printing the numbers.

Comment: you really should format your code to be consistent when posting questions where there is more code than supplementary text; It takes more time to realign the code to make it readable than answering the question. Humans deal with complexity through patterns.

Answer (score 2):

You are just summing up values but you are missing the division by the length of the array:

```
private static double getAverage(double[] nums){
    double sum = 0;
    for (int y= 0; y < nums.length; y++)
    {
        sum= sum + nums[y];
    }    
    return sum / nums.length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to kick yourself for this.

```
private static double getAverage(double[] nums){
      double sum = 0;
      for (int y= 0; y < nums.length; y++)
      {
         sum= sum + nums[y];
      }    
      return sum;
         }
```

You never divide the sum by the length here. The "average" is actually the sum.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, your method getAverage() does not return the average, it returns the sum.

Replace the line 
`return sum;`

by 
`return (sum / nums.length);`